# Compare previous list element using the apply function family R, get rid of for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I am always looking to minimize my use of for loops in R. Is there anyway to compare the current element to a previous element in the list without a for loop? Here is a simplified version of the problem I am working on.

I want to mark the First_Transaction column as a 1 if it is the persons's first transaction. The data is already sorted by person and date.

```
   Name Amount Date First_Transaction 
1   Joe 50  01/05/15    0
2   Joe 43  02/05/15    0
3   Joe 40  03/05/15    0
4   Tom 40  01/03/15    0
5   Tom 34  01/29/15    0
6   Tom 22  02/05/15    0
7   Tom 49  02/10/15    0
8   Kim 28  03/10/15    0
9   Kim 19  03/20/15    0
10  Kim 24  04/13/15    0
11  Kim 35  04/20/15    0
```

Using a for loop, I mark the first row a 1 then use logic to check if the current name matches the previous name. If it does not, mark the First_Transaction column 1.

```
test$First_Transaction[1]=1

for(i in 2:length(test$Name)){
  if(test$Name[i] != test$Name[i-1]){
    test$First_Transaction[i]=1
  }
```

Is there an apply family function that can implement this logic? I really want to figure out how to do this without the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the first observation of "First_Transaction" should be changed to "1" for each group of "Name", we could use `ave`

```
 df1$First_Transaction <- as.numeric(with(df1, 
         ave(seq_along(First_Transaction),Name, FUN=seq_along)==1))
```

or we could compare the current element of "Name" with the next element

```
 as.numeric(with(df1, c(TRUE, Name[-1]!=Name[-nrow(df1)])))
```

Or use `duplicated`

```
 as.numeric(!duplicated(df1$Name))
```